# Returning JSON object using jquery as a string (XSS)

Tags: jquery, json

1. I'm using jquery to display a returned JSON file, however, I want to 
   display the returned object as a string to mitigate XSS, so the value is displayed as plain text and is iterated through. This is part of the statement which displays the values. escape inputs "%20" between 
   strings. What is the best practice to do this?

   ```
   if (myObj.value === undefined || myObj.value === null){
       extrahtml += '<td>' + "" + '</td>';
   } else { 
       extrahtml += '<td>' + escape(myObj.value) + '</td>';
   }
   ```

Comment: The question is very unclear.  Can you post a **[mcve]** so we can see input, output and expected results?

Comment: JSON can always be displayed as a string, because it **is** a string.  If it is an object and you want to display it as JSON, you have to JSON.stringify() it.